# .Net Enterprise Library DAAB - Using Accessors to get Stored Proc Output params and Return values

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library, data-access-app-block

How to access stored procedure output parameters and/or return values using the Accessors in DotNet Enterprise Library Data Access Block ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Return values and output parameters are explicitly not supported when using accessors. Use one of the other DAAB methods instead.

Comment: What do you mean by use one of the other DAAB methods instead? Sorry for the newbie question, but when you say accessors, are you referring to the DbCommand objects and DbParameter objects? I am using DAAB to call a stored proc and I have an issue with getting output parameters. My question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39985999/microsoft-practices-enterpriselibrary-data-database-addout-parameter-not-getting

Answer (score 0):

```
Database.GetParameterValue(command, "paramName");
```